# Why does Play 2.3.4 and jacoco4sbt > 2.1.4 fail with NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: scala, sbt, jacoco, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to use jacoco4sbt in my Play 2.3.4 (scala 2.10.4) app but only 2.1.4 seems to work. When I use .5 or .6, I get the following error:

```
[error] (main/jacoco:fullClasspath) java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
```

I tried to add `asm-all` (versions 4.1 and 5.0.3) to the dependencies but this does not help at all.

So what could be the problem? Do I need to add any extra dependency?

Comment: Could you please ask another question (so we don't hijack this one), add the solution with PMD as an answer and approve. That makes SO cleaner.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Thanks for your help here. I added the update info to a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26288867/1205368).

Comment: Thanks! Excellent cooperation. Love that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at Jacek answer and started removing things from my project, I found that this was cause by some [custom task](https://github.com/ymasory/sbt-code-quality.g8) to run [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net) that I was not aware of, which probably depends on a different asm version.

To fix this I just changed the dependency in `project/plugins.sbt` to exclude asm dependency:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // (...)
  "net.sourceforge.pmd" % "pmd" % "5.1.3" exclude("org.ow2.asm", "asm")
)
```

and both Jacoco and PMD started working again.

Answer (score 1):

[They have indeed changed the ASM version](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/commit/488550f5176f005ab78b70fe7439db57f4a442ed) to 5.0.1, and even with this I couldn't reproduce your issue.

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.7-M3
```

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.4")
```

**plugins/jacoco4sbt.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "jacoco4sbt" % "2.1.6")
```

**build.sbt**

```
name := """play-jacoco"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws
)

pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, digest, gzip)

jacoco.settings
```

When I ran `jacoco:cover` it worked fine.

```
[play-uglify] $ jacoco:cover
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /Users/jacek/sandbox/play-uglify/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
SLF4J: The following set of substitute loggers may have been accessed
SLF4J: during the initialization phase. Logging calls during this
SLF4J: phase were not honored. However, subsequent logging calls to these
SLF4J: loggers will work as normally expected.
SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#substituteLogger
SLF4J: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
SLF4J: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl
SLF4J: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter
SLF4J: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler
SLF4J: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration
SLF4J: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient
SLF4J: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine
SLF4J: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebResponse
[info] IntegrationSpec
[info]
[info] Application should
[info] + work from within a browser
[info]
[info] Total for specification IntegrationSpec
[info] Finished in 29 ms
[info] 1 example, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] ApplicationSpec
[info]
[info] Application should
[info] + send 404 on a bad request
[info] + render the index page
[info]
[info] Total for specification ApplicationSpec
[info] Finished in 29 ms
[info] 2 examples, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] Passed: Total 3, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 3
[info]
[info] ------- Jacoco Coverage Report --------
[info]
[info] Lines: 57.5% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 34 of 80 missed, OK
[info] Instructions: 72.12% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 522 of 1872 missed, OK
[info] Branches: 27.78% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 26 of 36 missed, OK
[info] Methods: 81.94% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 41 of 227 missed, OK
[info] Complexity: 76.73% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 57 of 245 missed, OK
[info] Class: 57.14% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 12 of 28 missed, OK
[info] Check /Users/jacek/sandbox/play-uglify/target/scala-2.11/jacoco for detail report
[info]
[success] Total time: 6 s, completed Oct 9, 2014 7:42:31 AM
```

Where do we differ?