# How to set up jacoco4sbt to process classes in main and submodules in Play?

Tags: scala, sbt, jacoco, playframework-2.3

I'm having some problems to make [jacoco4sbt](https://github.com/sbt/jacoco4sbt) working with my Play 2.3.4 project.

My project is composed of 3 submodules: `common`, `api` and `frontend` and has no code in the `app` root folder. Now when I run Jacoco it does not find the submodules classes.

Inspecting `target/scala-VERSION/classes` I only find some routing classes (which in fact is the only code I have in my "root" project, but I was expecting that because I aggregate all those projects the classes would be there).

If I copy the classes from `MODULE_NAME/target/scala-VERSION/classes` to `target/scala-VERSION/classes` and then run Jacoco I get the expected result.

So what is the best way to make it work? I can't find any config in jacoco4sbt to specify additional classes locations.

My build.sbt file

```
import Keys._

// Dummy value to deal with bug in sbt 0.13.5
val k = 0

name := "PlayApp"

version := "0.5.0"

// omitted resolvers part

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.edulify" %% "play-hikaricp" % "1.5.0" exclude("com.jolbox", "bonecp"),
    "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test"
)

lazy val common = project.in(file("common")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

lazy val frontend = project.in(file("frontend")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).dependsOn(common)

lazy val api = project.in(file("api")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).dependsOn(common)

lazy val main = project.in(file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
    .aggregate(frontend, api).dependsOn(frontend, api)

parallelExecution in Test := false

javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.resource=test.conf"
```

jacoco.sbt

```
import de.johoop.jacoco4sbt._
import JacocoPlugin._


jacoco.settings

Keys.fork in jacoco.Config := true

parallelExecution in jacoco.Config := false

jacoco.outputDirectory in jacoco.Config := file("target/jacoco")

jacoco.reportFormats in jacoco.Config := Seq(XMLReport("utf-8"), HTMLReport("utf-8"))

jacoco.excludes in jacoco.Config := Seq("views*", "*Routes*", "controllers*routes*", "controllers*Reverse*", "controllers*javascript*", "controller*ref*")

javaOptions in jacoco.Config  += "-Dconfig.resource=test.conf"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `jacoco.sbt` to **every** subproject with the following content:

```
jacoco.settings
```

p.s. I've been looking for ways to convince sbt to have `jacoco.settings` applied to every subproject in  the top-level root `build.sbt`, but to no avail.